# User input box to pick column to perform action

Tags: vba, excel, macros

Okay i am very new to VBA coding.

I am working on a program that finds matches within a column and cuts and pastes them onto a separate sheet. I have working code that does this however i would like to broaden it so that there is an input box where user can pick which column for the program to search through, find matches, and cut and paste these onto sheet 2. Here is what I have, any help would be awesome. I know the code is a little clunky as well so any help cleaning it up would be awesome.

Thanks guys.

```
 Sub removedup()
Dim y As Integer
Dim x As Integer
Dim z As Integer
Dim unique() As String
ReDim unique(0)
Dim dups() As String
ReDim dups(0)
Dim dupFlag As Boolean
Dim dupCount As Integer
Dim rowcount As Integer
Dim sheet2indexer As Integer
Dim rColumn As Range



    Set rColumn = Application.InputBox("Pick Column", , , , , , , 8)

    MsgBox rColumn.Address




'Pre Sort

Cells.Select
    ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet1").Sort.SortFields.Clear
    ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet1").Sort.SortFields.Add Key:=Range(rColumn.Column)_
        , SortOn:=xlSortOnValues, Order:=xlAscending, DataOption:=xlSortNormal
    With ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet1").Sort
        .SetRange Range("A1:Z20000")
        .Header = xlGuess
        .MatchCase = False
        .Orientation = xlTopToBottom
        .SortMethod = xlPinYin
        .Apply
    End With

'get array of all unique names
dupFlag = False
x = 1
Do While Sheets(1).Cells(x, rColumn.Column).Value <> ""
    For y = 0 To UBound(unique)
        If Sheets(1).Cells(x, "E").Value = unique(y) Then
            dupFlag = True
        End If
    Next y
    If dupFlag = False Then
        ReDim Preserve unique(UBound(unique) + 1)
        unique(UBound(unique)) = Sheets(1).Cells(x, rColumn.Column).Value
    Else
        dupFlag = False
    End If

x = x + 1

Loop

rowcount = x - 1

'unique(1 to unbound(unique)) now contains one of each entry
'check which values are duplicates, and record

dupCount = 0

For y = 1 To UBound(unique)
    x = 1
    Do While Sheets(1).Cells(x, rColumn.Column).Value <> ""
        If unique(y) = Sheets(1).Cells(x, rColumn.Column).Value Then
            dupCount = dupCount + 1
        End If
        x = x + 1
    Loop
    If dupCount > 1 Then
        'unique(y) is found more than once
        ReDim Preserve dups(UBound(dups) + 1)
        dups(UBound(dups)) = unique(y)
    End If
        dupCount = 0
Next y

sheet2indexer = 0
'now we have a list of all duplicate entries, time to start moving rows
For z = rowcount To 1 Step -1
    For y = 1 To UBound(dups)
        If Sheets(1).Cells(z, rColumn.Column).Value = dups(y) Then
            'current row z is a duplicate
            sheet2indexer = sheet2indexer + 1
            Sheets(1).Rows(z).Cut Sheets(2).Rows(sheet2indexer)
            Sheets(1).Rows(z).Delete
        End If
    Next y
Next z


End Sub
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to select a range variable using an `InputBox`, you can supply the value `8` to its last argument. Then, you can select a Range (or an entire column) upon which to work.

For example:

```
Sub Test()
    Dim rColumn As Range

    Set rColumn = Application.InputBox("Pick Col", , , , , , , 8)

    MsgBox rColumn.Address
End Sub
```

Comment: And then for example in my macro above would i replace all of my current "E" s with rColumn?

Comment: @Uriahfb In the `.Cells` method, you can supply either a letter or a number for the column. If the user selected the entire column, the range address would be `E:E`, which doesn't work. Instead, convert it to a number by using `rColumn.Column`. The end result is something similar to: `.Cells(2, rColumn.Column).Value`. Let me know if more assistance is needed.

Comment: Okay so i just changed all of my code over to the rColumn.column but am getting an error saying the reference you typed is not valid or you did not provide a reference where one was required. i tried entering a number and letters and got the same error.@user3561813

Comment: Can you quickly debug to make sure that it's being read correctly? After setting `rColumn`, type a line such as `MsgBox rColumn.Address`. Make sure the message box contains the range you selected ("$E:$E" for example). If this works correctly, can you point to the specific line of code that throws the error?

Comment: It does not seem to be setting rColumn at all, it says the reference typed is not valid and does not give me anything in the message box. I have separated the piece of code u supplied above into its own macro to test it, and am getting the same error.

Comment: For the sake of completeness, can you post the separated piece of code for our review (it might be easiest to edit the original post and supply it in there).

Comment: Okay i updated the original post to where I have it now, when the user input box pops up and you enter a number or a letter into the box it does not accept it, saying reference you typed is not valid or you did not provide a reference where one was required

Comment: Ok, I understand the issue. When you supply type `8` as the last parameter to the `InputBox` function, the code is looking for a range object. You can set that in one of two way. (1) Physically select the cell or column by clicking on the cell or column header while the input box is open, or (2) typing in a valid cell or column reference (such as `E1` for cell `E1` or `E:E` for the entire column). Note, since we are interested in the column number, either of these options will return the same column number.

Comment: Okay we are close now im sure this is a quick fix but i am getting the error method 'range' of object '_global' failed on lines ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet1").Sort.SortFields.Add Key:=Range("rColumn.Column") _
        , SortOn:=xlSortOnValues, Order:=xlAscending, DataOption:=xlSortNormal

Comment: `rColumn.Column` returns a number (the column of the range). And we also know that `Range(...)` takes a cell/group of cells. Typing `Range(5)` throws an error. We have to fix this by enforcing some type of business rule that you'd have to define. For example, in this circumstance, you can reference `rColumn` directly. But what if the user only selected one cell. You can take `rColumn.EntireColumn`. What if you don't want the whole column, but only a range... Determine your need, and we can help from there.

Comment: It will always be an entire column that they select. I have changed my user input box to ask them to click on the column they would like to find matches in. After changing it to Range(rColumn.EntireColumn) i am getting the same error.

Comment: That's because `rColumn.EntireColumn` is already a `Range` object, so you don't have to wrap it with `Range()`. Simply type `rColumn.EntireColumn`.

Comment: Actually, since it's always an entire column, it would be a better practice to set the entire column into the `rColumn` variable from the start. Amend the `InputBox` code to read: `Set rColumn = Application.InputBox("Pick Col", , , , , , , 8).EntireColumn` . Now, `rColumn` is a Range object to refers to the entire column. When you need to use the numeric value of the column, you can still use `rColumn.Column`

Comment: No problem. Consider marking the question as answered so that future users know that we have a working solution.

Comment: How would one go about doing that?

Comment: The community standards are pretty well covered here: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work