# How does one write a VBA macro which generates a SUMIFS table using a user selected column as an input in the formula?

Tags: excel, vba

Not sure if this is even possible but I'm just curious. I know you can make VBA automatically populate a formula in certain cells in Excel, and also that you can insert columns and such next to a user selected cell. Is it possible however to write a code in which the user selects a column that contains data 1 (dates for example), and then selects a column with data 2 (names for example) and a final column with data 3 (dollar values). Then the code would run on a predefined range (a table that has names as row headers and dates as column headers) and populate a SUMIFS formula into all the cells- with the user selected columns as the criteria range and the defined name rows and date columns as the criteria.

If someone can point me on the right direction I'd greatly appreciate this. I'm struggling to figure out how to structure this macro so that a user input variable can be used inside the SUMIFS formula, changing the criteria range in the formula based on what the user selects. Let me know if this even seems possible in VBA.

I've tried creating macros which automatically populate a formula like SUMIF into a range, but the problem is that the formula has to be fixed in the VBA code with certain constants. What I'm looking for would have to be variable, and the parameters of the formula be taken from user inputs.

Appreciate any help or knowledge on this topic. Thanks.

Comment: Welcome to SO. Please show us what you have tried so far. Reading [ask] and [repro] will help you to improve your question.

Answer (score 0):

In code I used before I needed to be able to select a column and then use it later on,

```
On Error Resume Next
Set columnStart = Application.InputBox("Select the column of the first key", Default:=Selection.Address(0, 0), Type:=8)
On Error GoTo 0
If columnStart Is Nothing Then
    MsgBox "Cancelled."
    GoTo EndSkip
End If
Set wbV = columnStart.Parent.Parent
columnAddress = columnStart.Address
columnNr = columnStart.Column
wbV.Activate
Set ws = wbV.ActiveSheet
```

and use it later on in a VLOOKUP

```
 Range("N2:N" & Lastrow).FormulaR1C1 = _
        "=IFERROR(VLOOKUP(RC[-1],'[" & wbV.Name & "]" & ws.Name & "'!C" & columnNr & ",1,0), ""0000NO"")"
```

This should help you how to use them as variables in a formula.
I believe my info came partly from here [User input box to pick column to perform action](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37703808/user-input-box-to-pick-column-to-perform-action)

Comment: Hey- thanks for your response. Would you know about the syntax required to make VBA input a SUMIFS formula into the cell? I tried to modify your code for my purposes but its simply inputting the value TRUE into the cell rather than the sum of the values. Code below.

Range("B2").FormulaR1C1 = _
    "=SUMIFS(" & columnNr2 & "," & columnNr & "," >="&" B1", " & columnNr & ", " <& $C1"," & columnNr3 & ",A:A)"

Comment: SUMIFS(" <- what's that " doing there? Maybe record your SUMIFS again and have a look at how it's formed, then adjust it to the variable format.